# Get information in a current appointment item to an addin

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, office-addins, comaddin

I'm pretty new to programming Outlook addins in VB.Net.  I want to send an email out with the recipients and the body of a meeting item when the ItemSend event is triggered.  How should I reference the appointment item I just sent?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the mailItem as a Private variable you should easily be able to access/reference it from the ItemSent event.

See this article for more info and as an example: http://codeidol.com/csharp/c-sharp-in-office/Working-with-Outlook-Events/Outlook-Item-Events/

Comment: It seems I can't declare as a new object. Every time I try `dim meet as new outlook.meetingitem` I get 'new is not available in this context because it is friend'

Comment: is this VBA or VSTO? what documentation are you following?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210951(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: sorry for not mentioning before, I'm trying to program a COM addin